# Passing remaining_accounts using anchor client side SDK

Tags: anchor-client

I am trying to pass remaining_accounts from the client side using the Anchor SDK, with the following code.

```
 const tx = await program.rpc.sendMonies(new anchor.BN(0), new anchor.BN(100), {
      accounts: {
        baseAccount: baseAccount.publicKey,
        remainingAccounts: [
          {pubkey: _ac1.publicKey, isWritable: true, isSigner: false},
          {pubkey: _ac2.publicKey, isWritable: true, isSigner: false},
          {pubkey: _ac3.publicKey, isWritable: true, isSigner: false}
        ],
        user: payingUser.publicKey
      },
      signers: [payingUser]
    });
```

Below is my program, where I log the number of remaining_accounts passed but, as you can see in the logs of this transaction the statement after "now transfer sol" logs 0. I even have a for-loop to iterate over the array of remaining accounts but that also doesn't run as the array is always empty.

```
msg!("now transfer sol");
msg!(ctx.remaining_accounts.len().to_string().as_str());
```

What am I doing wrong here? I highly suspect it is a problem with how I am passing the remaining accounts from the frontend.

Comment: you cite logs, but none were included in the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remaining accounts shouldn't be inside accounts, it's its own top level thing.

Like so

```
await program.rpc.sendMonies(new anchor.BN(0), new anchor.BN(100), {
      accounts: {
        baseAccount: baseAccount.publicKey,
        user: payingUser.publicKey
      },
      remainingAccounts: [
          {pubkey: _ac1.publicKey, isWritable: true, isSigner: false},
          {pubkey: _ac2.publicKey, isWritable: true, isSigner: false},
          {pubkey: _ac3.publicKey, isWritable: true, isSigner: false}
        ],
      signers: [payingUser]
    });
```